# How to automatically sync network folder and local folder in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, mount, nautilus, sync, google-drive

I am trying to sync between my local folder(say on Desktop) and google drive.  I followed this tutorial "[Easily Mount Google Drive](https://www.maketecheasier.com/mount-google-drive-ubuntu-1604/)" and was able to access google drive from nautilus(from the explorer window). Now I can drag and drop folders from anywhere onto this window and it uploads them to Google drive, which is nice, but I want to automate this process so that say a folder on my desktop keeps getting synced every week or so.

How do I go about doing this? I heard about cron job or something, but I am unable to access this google drive folder(which appears in nautilus manager) through command line itself to begin with.

Comment: There is no out-of-the-box command line client for Google Drive, just the Nautilus interface. There are some third-party clients though: Grive2, Insync, Ocamlfuse.

Comment: But I read that Insync and Ocamlfuse are not free? Are there free clients through which I can mainly "automate" this process?

Comment: I googled a bit more and came up with this: https://github.com/odeke-em/drive

Answer (score 1):

Consider [drive](https://github.com/odeke-em/drive).

It is a free, open source command line utility that can copy files and folders to (`push`) and from(`pull`) a Google Drive. The usage is quite extensive, and with some wise parameter choices I suppose a complete sync job could be made.

It uses an initial `drive init` command to ask for your Google user's permissions in a web browser. However, it can also run with an OAuth2 service credentials file instead.